# How to handle columns of the same name in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe which happens to have some columns with the same column name.

```
df_raw[column_name] # [141 rows x 2 columns]
```

I have a code that extracts the unique values but it does not work if it has more than one dimension.

```
ipdb> dt_raw[column_name].unique()
*** AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'unique'
```

I wish to not "update" with the df_raw.columns to make all columns unique before processing.  Is there a good way to handle this?

I have tried the code below with error:

```
ipdb> dt_raw[column_name][0]
*** KeyError: 0
```

Questions:

1. How to know how many columns have the same name.  In the example above, I am expecting 2.
2. How to individually refer to a column (for example, updating purposes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the number of columns with `column_name`, you can do `df_raw[column_name].shape[1]`. You can access a dataframe by actual location, rather than name, with the `iloc` syntax: `df_raw.iloc[:,n]` will return the nth column of the dataframe, and `df_raw[column_name].iloc[:,n]` will return the nth column named "column_name" (keep in mind that it's zero-indexed).

Also, if you want the unique column names, you can do `set(df_raw.columns)`.

Comment: Yes, df_raw[column_name].shape[1] works, i got 2.   The df_raw.iloc[column_name][:,0] did not work though - *** TypeError: cannot do positional indexing on <class 'pandas.indexes.numeric.Int64Index'> with these indexers [MASKED COLUMN NAME] of <class 'str'>.  Anyway thank you for your response.  I have found a working code few minutes back.

Comment: @Earl Whoops, sorry about that. It should be `df_raw[column_name].iloc[:,n] `.

Comment: @Accumulation yes it is working.  It is interesting pandas have different ways to do the same thing.  Looks like in this case .iloc and .ix performs the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer.  Thank you for viewing.

1. How to know how many columns have the same name. In the example above, I am expecting 2.

> ```
> len(df_raw[column_name].columns)
> ```

2. How to individually refer to a column (for example, updating purposes).

> ```
> df_raw[column_name].ix[:,0]  #first column
> df_raw[column_name].ix[:,1]  #2nd column, etc
> ```